# AmazonS3 getObjectInfo 404 error

Tags: amazon-s3

getObjectInfo is giving 404 error every time but the file is present in S3.
please provide me an alternate option to chech if the image exists in amazon S3

Comment: Provide more info, it seems that the file is not reachable.

Comment: wanted to validate the images before saving it on s3 so that I can reduce redundancy but it always throwing 404 error even if it present in s3 .

Comment: Please show your code.  If the object is present, it should not return 404.